# "Determine the zero divisors, nilpotents and the non-invertibles in $ \mathbb{Q}[x] /(x^{4}-2x^{3}+3x^{2}-4x+2)$"

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, nilpotence

Good evening,

I would like to ask the following exercise :

"Determine the zero divisors, nilpotents and the non-invertibles in $ \mathbb{Q}[x] /(x^{4}-2x^{3}+3x^{2}-4x+2)$"

I saw that the polynomial can be factorized as $(x-1)^{2}(x^2+2)$ if i am not mistaken, but what really i am not fully understanding is that i always worked with finite fields or ring, 
like (for example) $ \mathbb{Z}/_{5 \mathbb{Z}} $ where i could at least used that  $ \mathbb{Z}/_{5 \mathbb{Z}} $ was the union of the Invertibles and the Zero-divisors.

Or maybe use the fact that a generic Invertible polynomial $ h(x) $ is Invertible $\iff (f(x),h(x))=1 $, where $f(x)=(x-1)^{2}(x^2+2)$.

(And so on for Zero-divisors and Nilpotents).

Here my guess is that there are infinite polynomials because of $|\mathbb{Q}| = +\infty  $, but i don't know (if my guess is true) how to prove or how to caracterize those classes.

Any help or tips would be appreciated,

Thank you all

Comment: It is a good idea to make a parallel to $\Bbb Z$ and ideals in $\Bbb Z$. Instead of the prime=irreducible polynomials $(x-1)$ and $(x^2+2)$ in $\Bbb Q[x]$ let us consider the prime=irreducible elements $7,19$ in $\Bbb Z$. We then consider the ring $R=\Bbb Z/7^2\cdot 19\cong \Bbb Z/7^2\times \Bbb Z/19$. Which are here the   zero divisors, nilpotents and the non-invertibles...?!

Comment: I'm sorry,editing it! @DietrichBurde

Comment: I'm not sure i clearly get the analogy,but i will work on that, thanks @dan_fulea

Comment: $ \mathbb{Q}[x] /(x^{4}-2x^{3}+3x^{2}-4x+2)$ ? @DietrichBurde

Comment: Yes, the quotient is $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for a primitive element, so an infinite ring. For example $\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x-2)\cong \Bbb{Q}$, which is certainly infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)$ be a zero divisor. Then $\exists h,k \not = 0 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ s.t. $g(x)h(x) = 0 = k(x)(x-1)^2(x^2+2)$. Now note that niether $g$ nor $h$ can have both $(x-1)^2$ and $x^2+2$ as factors, as otherwise they would be zero. Now going through all the combinations yields that $g(x)$ is of the forms:

$$(x-1)p(x)\quad \quad (x-1)^2p(x) \quad \quad (x^2+2)p(x) \quad \quad(x-1)(x^2+2)p(x)$$

where $\gcd(p(x),x^{4}-2x^{3}+3x^{2}-4x+2) = 1$

To find the nilpotent element using the unique factorization in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ we can conclude that both factors of  $x^{4}-2x^{3}+3x^{2}-4x+2$ must appear in the prime factorization of a nilpotent element. Thus all nilpotent elements are of the form:

$$(x-1)^k(x^2+2)^np(x)$$

where again $\gcd(p(x),x^{4}-2x^{3}+3x^{2}-4x+2) = 1$

Finally to find the invertibles you can use the Euclidean Algorithm that says that $g(x)$ is invertible iff $\gcd(g(x),x^{4}-2x^{3}+3x^{2}-4x+2) = 1$